# how to remove a file from a commit which is not pushed to server in git?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I mistakenly, add a big file binary to one of my commits and now the commit is too big to be pushed to server. As it is on my own computer and I did not push it, how I can remove it from the commit? I can not create another commit to revert back the original commit since then I can not push these commits to server.

I am using Bitbucket and sourcetree for git management.

Comment: Is it the last commit on the branch? If so, you can run `git rm --cached <file-in-question>`, then `git commit --amend --no-edit` (I don't know how to do that in SourceTree, sorry). Or is it an older commit?

Comment: @Jubobs It is the last commit.

Comment: @Jubobs based on your answer, I found how to do this in sourcetree and fixed the problem. Please put it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well, since you were asking specifically about SourceTree, perhaps you should post a self answer, instead.